# Weird Oracle behaviour - cross join in recursive CTE works with comma but not with cross join clause

Tags: oracle, cycle, recursive-query, cross-join

Suppose following simple recursive query `r` to list several numbers. When recursive part of query is cross joined with unnecessary 1-row table using old way with comma separation, everything works fine ([dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=25414d703ebd32b497f3a7d9105be772)):

```
with r (x) as (
  select 1 as x from dual
  union all
  select x + 1 from r,dual where x < 5
)
select * from r
```

If I change comma to `cross join` clause, I get `ORA-32044: cycle detected while executing recursive WITH query` error ([dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=06f577f33a72cc342e9bdadf6ad30331)):

```
with r (x) as (
  select 1 as x from dual
  union all
  select x + 1 from r cross join dual where x < 5
)
select * from r;
```

Reproduced on Oracle 11g (my project db) and Oracle 18 (dbfiddle). The case is minimized, originally it is hierarchical query on graph data where auxiliary relation with 2 rows representing edge endpoints was cross joined in such a way.

I can (unwillingly) live with first syntax though I have bad feeling of dark undocumented corner or Oracle to build query upon. I didn't find any reasoning for such behaviour nor track of bug. Do anybody knows any? Thanks.

Comment: I can reproduce with Oracle 19.5. It looks like a bug. If you have an Oracle support contract, you know what you have to do otherwise you can ask this question on https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:1000:::::: to have a free answer from Oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest explanation I've found until now is in [this thread](https://community.oracle.com/message/11033072#11033072) on MOS. In the thread, OP effectively joins tables with inner join with join condition in `where` clause. In `from` clause there are just two tables connected with either `cross join` or comma. My example differs in aspect the `dual table` is not involved in any join condition, which weakens some reasonings in thread such as *anything involving 2 different tables is recognized as a join condition*.

Anyway, it seems Oracle actually evaluates comma-separated tables as inner join, which - for some unknown reason - orders differently in evaluation of recursion loop. If I change join condition to inner join on true - `from r inner join dual on r.x = r.x` - the query also succeeds, which supports this guess.

I set up [own thread](https://community.oracle.com/thread/4333244?start=0&tstart=0) on MOS for this problem. There is also answer suspecting bug but without clearer explanation.

Summary: currently it's not clear whether it is a bug or some undocumented feature. Separation with comma and join condition in `where` clause seem to be the safest way in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

Using the first recursive query, you will get 5 records, when you try to cross join on the recursive result, each time it iterates the data, for each iteration according to the value 5, the values gets looped against each other resulting in, `ORA-32044: cycle detected while executing recursive WITH query` error. Instead you have to cross join out side the recursive result as below,

```
with r (x) as (
  select 1 as x from dual
  union all
select x + 1 from r,dual where x < 5
)
select * from r
cross join r;
```

Comment: This will give a very different result - 25 rows with two columns, instead of 5 rows with one column?

Comment: Thanks for response Jim, my intention is not to cross join relation `r` with itself. My intention is to cross join relation `r` with dummy table (looks silly in minimalistic example but makes sense in real) which has limited number of rows (1 in example, 2 actually though it imho does not matter).

Comment: Please provide the expected result, so that can help you

Comment: Expected result is table with 1 column, 5 rows and values 1 to 5 as returned from first query in my question. My question is rather about the reason of different behaviour of two kinds of syntax which I thought they were equivalent until now.

Comment: Both will not provide you same behavior. Respective to the iterations, cyclic range would differ as i explained in the answer

Comment: I don't understand the _for each iteration according to the value 5, the values gets looped against each other_ sentence. I expect every new level of recursive query appends only one new row into result, regardless if dual table is joined or not. Why should db engine process value again?

Answer (score 2):

You can add the cycle clause to solve it:

```
with r (x) as (
      select 1 as x from dual
      union all
      select x + 1   from r cross join dual where x < 5
    ) cycle x set is_cycle to 1 default 0 
    select * from r;
```

Gives the required result.

Comment: Worth noting that `is_cycle` comes out as 0, further supporting that this is a bug.

Comment: Yep, I suspect that in the transformation in the optimizer, something is going wrong and this is inhibited by the cycle clause